# regex for /* ... */

Tags: c#, regex

I wanted to replace all occurrences of `"/* anytext here */"` with a blank space (where `anytext here` could be different types of texts.) What I'm trying to do is replace all comments with blanks.

I created a regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/\*.*\*/");
```

...but it does not consider the presence of multiple `/* ... */` patterns. For example, this string:

```
"she /*sells*/ sea shells /*by the*/ sea shore"
```

...becomes:

```
"she   sea shore"
```

...whereas what I want is:

```
"she   sea shells   sea shore"
```

Can someone help with the correct regex?

Comment: Any reason `string.Split` and `string.Replace` will not do?

Comment: In your regex, because astrisk is a special character, you must escape it with a backwards slash (or whatever "\" is).

Comment: @Matthew, the backslashes were there all along, but they weren't displayed because the OP didn't use code formatting.

Answer (score 10):

Use a *lazy* quantifier (`.*?`) instead of a *greedy* one (`.*`). By the way, your literal `*` characters need to be escaped with `\*`:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"/\*.*?\*/");
```

A lazy quantifier tries to match *as little as possible* (= to the first `*/`), whereas a greedy quantifier matches *as much as possible* (= to the last `*/`). More details can be found at the following MSDN page:

- [Regular Expressions: Greedy and Lazy Quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374.aspx#Greedy)

Comment: You'll probably want to enable DOT-ALL: by default, most regex implementations will not let the `.` match line-break chars.